# How to track how much time other app is used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i want to track how much time other apps in device are used by the user, i want track that time inside my app.for ex. i want track how much time user used the Facebook app, or WhatsApp or any other app.

is there any way to do this...please give any suggestions or example code or any other tutorials..

Thanks,
raki.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple don't allow tracking when you are out of your app, for tracking time and user activity in my apps, I use [flurry](http://www.flurry.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can track how long people use your app, sure. One popular way is via [Google Analytics iOS SDK](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

For tracking other apps on the users device, that is simply not possible. You do not have access to other apps you have not developed yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. Apple forbid apps trying to access things outside of their sandbox.